# Work Visa Application Germany - How do I turn in my certified Copy of Diploma?

Tags: working-visas, education, certification

I'm a recent graduate with an internship offer in Berlin, Germany. I'm putting together my visa application and it appears they would like proof of my qualifications (which I'm guessing is my college diploma). The form says I can turn these in within two weeks of handing in my visa application, but it doesn't specify exactly how I can do this. It says to turn it in to the relevant employment office. Does that mean the Bundesagentur für Arbeit? Do I have to make an appointment to do that, and how long will it take me? Can I just drop it off?

Answer (score 3):

If it says Proof of Qualifications than you need your Diploma to be assessed by the [ZAB](http://www.anerkennung-in-deutschland.de/html/en/assessment_of_higher_education_certificates.php)

You should follow the instructions in their site. Basically you need to fill out a form and mail the required documents to them. Do not send the original ones, make legal copies.

They will mail you back a certification if your education is University, Faculty etc.

--

But your employee will also need to make an application to the Bundesagentur für Arbeit and needs these documents (I mean your diploma) so make sure to make extra copies of the legal copies.